# how do I store an image in views file in Django

Tags: django

I am making a Django website where I need to display images selected by user. 
These are the things I've done:

Html form for image:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
<div class="form-group">
            <label >Article Logo</label>
            <input type="file" class="btn btn-primary" name="article_image">
 </div>
 <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success">
 </form>
```

models.py

```
class Content(models.Model):
        article_image = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'media', null=True)
```

views.py

```
def submit_article(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
             a_image = request.FILES['article_image']
             new_article.article_image = a_image
             new_article.save()
```

I've added below code to settings.py to specify media directory:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Added below code to urls.py of the website:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path(r'admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'', include('logio.urls')),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

The form is not able to add images to the media folder. If I'm adding images through the admin panel it works.

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to your form, like this:

```
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{% csrf_token %}
```

For more information, please check the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/file-uploads/#basic-file-uploads).

Just a suggestion, it is better to use a [Django form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/) to handle this. For example, you can have a form:

```
class ContentForm(forms.ModelForm):
     class Meta:
        model = Content
        fields = ['article_image']
```

Then pass this form via context to template and render it:

```
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{% csrf_token %}
  {{ form }}
  <input type="submit" value="submit'>
</form>
```

Finally, handle validation in view:

```
def submit_article(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
         form = ContentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
         if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            ...
```